# LWC: getting a list of Contacts in a picklist for every row of the table

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I'm creating a table by looping a list of Events (inside the html file of the LWC) and need to populate its rows with values that aren't directly stored in the Event object. More specifically, there is a column named  "Contacts" that has to display a picklist containing all of the contacts linked to the related account (Event -> Account -> Contact). I have written a basic method inside my Apex controller and I have figured out how to send the Event.WhatId as a parameter of that same method, but I'm failing to understand how all the different rows can populate dynamically.

Please check below code for more info:

**.html**

```
<template for:each={recordList} for:item="event">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={event.WhatId}>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account-Name-Row">{event.Account.Name}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contacts-Row">
                <lightning-combobox>
                ???
                </lightning-combobox>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="City-Row">{event.Account.BillingCity}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Start-Date-Row">
                <lightning-input type="date"
                                 name="event-start-date"
                                 onchange={handleEventStartChange}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="End-Date-Row">
                <lightning-input type="date"
                                 name="event-end-date"
                                 onchange={handleEventEndChange}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

**.cls**

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List <Contact> getContacts (String acctId)
{
    List <Contact> contList = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :acctId];
    return contList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide the value (an Id) and the list of possible values (arranged as {value,label} pairs). The relevant wired method would be:

```
contactOptions = [];
@wire(getContacts,{acctId: '$recordId'})
wireContactResponse({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.contactOptions = data.map(record => ({ value: record.Id, label: record.Name }));
    this.error = null;
  }
  if(error) {
    this.contactOptions = [];
    this.error = error;
  }
}
```

And in your markup:

```
<lightning-combobox label="Contact" options={contactOptions} value={event.WhoId}>
</lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help! I have used your code but, unfortunately, it's not working since the picklist isn't showing any value. I've also put a console.log right before and after the call to the apex method and nothing showed up.

Comment: @antoinedoinel You need to provide a recordId value. I don't have enough code from your question to figure out how to make that happen, but that's the piece you're likely missing. See [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) for more information.